# Website always hangs using python requests library

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to use the python requests library to get the html from this url https://www.adidas.com/api/products/EF2302/availability?sitePath=us

However every time I run my code it hangs when making the get request

```
header = BASE_REQUEST_HEADER
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/api/products/EF2302/availability?sitePath=us'
r = requests.get(url, headers = header)
```

I checked the network tab in chrome and copied all the headers used including user agent so that is not the issue. I was also able to load the page in chrome with javascript and cookies disabled.

This code works fine with other websites. I simply cant get a response from any of the adidas websites (including https://www.adidas.com/us).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a public API, or did you find it by reverse engineering their website? If it's not a public API, did you read their terms & conditions? Most sites explicitly say that you're not allowed to use automated tools to access their website without permission. And they usually back that up by either automated anti-scraper code, or semi-automated code that raises flags for their ops team; either way, making your requests hang is pretty easy for them to do. And there's nothing you can do about it. If you manage to find a way around their detection or enforcement, they can just change it.

Answer (score 2):

This site doesn't like the default User-Agent field supplied by requests, change it to Firefox/Chrome (I chose Firefox in my example), and you can read data successfully:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/api/products/EF2302/availability?sitePath=us'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "id": "EF2302",
    "availability_status": "PREORDER",
    "variation_list": [
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_530",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "4",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_550",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "5",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_570",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "6",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_590",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "7",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_610",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "8",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_630",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "9",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_650",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "10",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_670",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "11",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_690",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "12",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sku": "EF2302_710",
            "availability": 15,
            "availability_status": "PREORDER",
            "size": "13",
            "instock_date": "2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that this is almost certainly in violation of terms.

Answer (score 1):

One different is the User-agent field, which requests sets as 
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4

Adidas may be just dropping these http requests to stop people abusing their system.

(btw, it also happens for just www.adidas.com)

I reproduced the issue and took a look at wireshark packet sniffer. It seems the http request is good and there is tcp acknowledgement but no http reply.